# Test if function was called with Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have I button that triggers an handler on click:

```
<Button
  label="Test"
  onClick={(e) =>
    buttonHandler(e, fileName)
  }
/>
```

The handler looks like this:

```
const buttonHandler = (
  e: any,
  fileName: string,
) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fileName === "test" && functionToTrigger();
};
```

How can I test if the `functionToTrigger()` method was called after clicking the button and if the `fileName` equals to `"test"`?

Comment: What kind of tests are you writing? You've tagged both [tag:unit-testing] _and_ [tag:e2e-testing] - Cypress (although you've also tagged [tag:jest]) is usually used for the latter, in which the tests absolutely should **not** know which functions are getting called (or even that React's involved). Test _behaviour_, not implementation.

Comment: I removed the wrong tags - sorry for that. I'm writing cypress component tests. The buttonHandler is placed inside a <Cell> component that is used in tables.

Comment: Given the call `buttonHandler(e)`, `fileName` is `undefined` and `functionToTrigger()` _isn't_ called. It's unclear what `functionToTrigger` does or where it is even defined - if it's an external collaborator maybe you want to mock it, but if it's defined inside the component you can't, for example. Give a [mre].

Comment: It is simple. The button is placed inside a Cell component. If someone clicks the button, the buttonHandler gets triggered. If the passed fileName equals to the string "test" then the functionToTrigger method should be called. I had to simplify the code here a lot.

Comment: We still can't see where `fileName` and `functionToTrigger` are coming from. Simplifying is helpful, but it still needs to be something people can _run_ to recreate the issue. You haven't shown the tests at all.

Comment: fileName comes from the components props and functionToTrigger is imported from a service.

Comment: So [edit] the question - _show_, don't tell.